# Scala Lift - AJAX form not working correctly

Tags: ajax, scala, comet

I have the following AJAX form on my page:

```
<form class="lift:form.ajax">

    <div class="lift:StreamInput">

        <input type="hidden" name="path" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user" />
        <input type="hidden" name="level" />
        <input type="hidden" name="room" />

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="" />

</form>
```

Each of the input field values are set by a snippet that calls the DB.

When the form is submitted It's meant to send the values to the following:

```
import comet.StreamServer

object StreamInput {

    def render = {

        var path = ""
        var user = ""
        var level = ""
        var room = ""

        def process(): JsCmd = {

            val message = comet.StreamItem(user, path, level, room)
            StreamServer ! message

        }


        "name=path" #> SHtml.onSubmit(path = _) &
        "name=user" #> SHtml.onSubmit(user = _) &
        "name=level" #> SHtml.onSubmit(level = _) &
        "name=room" #> SHtml.onSubmit(room = _)

    }

}
```

From there as you can see, it's supposed to run the process method, build a "StreamItem" from the form data which is a case class contained in StreamServer and then send the object to the StreamServer to update listeners:

```
case class StreamItem(user: String, path: String, level: String, room: String)

class StreamComet extends CometActor with CometListener {

    private var streams: List[StreamItem] = Nil 

    def registerWith = StreamServer

    override def lowPriority = {

        case v: List[StreamItem] => 

            streams = v;
            reRender();

    }

    def addStreams(): String = {

        var script = ""

        streams.foreach{stream =>

            script += """

                STREAMMOD.stream_view.add_stream({ 

                    path : '""" + stream.path + """', 
                    level : '""" + stream.level + """'

                })

            """

        }

        return script

    }

    def render = {

        OnLoad(JsRaw(

            addStreams()

        ).cmd)

    }

}

object StreamServer extends LiftActor with ListenerManager {

    private var streams: List[StreamItem] = Nil

    def createUpdate = streams

    override def lowPriority = {

        case StreamItem(user, path, level, room) => {

            streams :+= StreamItem(user, path, level, room);
            updateListeners()

        }

    }

}
```

The end result should be a javascript function being called whcih sends the data to be displayed on the page.

When submitted though the data never seems to get that far, it just submits the form and then nothing happens.

What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.8.html#toc-Section-4.8

Comment: Ok I've found the specific issue, It seems the values from the form are not being correctly passed to the process method in StreamInput. What am I missing or doing incorrectly that means these values are lost?

Comment: I think the main problem is that there is no callback for the `process` method specified.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've noticed that if I change "val message = comet.StreamItem(user, path, level, room)" with static values all works as expected, so what callback should I be doing to set these values from the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Ajax form, the submit button isn't serialized over Ajax.  Instead, you typically create a hidden field, and bind your `process` callback to that field.  You can do that by changing the last line of your CSS selector to:

```
    "name=room" #> SHtml.onSubmit(room = _) &
    "name=room *+" #> SHtml.hidden(process)
```

This adds a hidden field to the form which invokes the `process` callback when the form is submitted.

There's more (but not a lot more) documented in [Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.8.html#toc-Section-4.8).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've changed the line you mentioned but am getting a compiler error "value ++ is not a member of (scala.xml.NodeSeq) => scala.xml.NodeSeq"

Comment: Hm.  Looks like onSubmit returns a function instead of just a NodeSeq.  I've made and edit that should work, but can't try it out at the moment.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: All is working as it should now after a bit of reading and help from other awesome members of stackoverflow, thanks again for all of the help :)